# Google Chrome "Unable to connect to Internet"

Tags: networking, google-chrome, dns

Google Chrome has stopped working. I am on a Windows 7 desktop that is connected to the Internet via an Ethernet cable run from my router. Chrome is up to date.

Trying to do any searches in Chrome brings up their dinosaur with the message "Unable to connect to Internet". The network icon recognizes that the cable is plugged in. And other browsers are working fine, but Chrome will not load anything. I followed this link while in the defective Chrome:

```
chrome://net-internals/#dns
```

and it says:

```
Default address family:
UNSPECIFIED
Async DNS Configuration

Internal DNS client enabled: false
```

What should I do? I've tried using the alternative DNS servers and flushing the DNS server but to no avail.

Comment: Do these "other browsers" include Internet Explorer? If so, then a proxy issue is unlikely (since both browsers share the same system settings in that regard). Did you test-wise disable your firewall to check that the issue does not stem from there? Apart from that: I can confirm that the DNS settings you listed above should be okay, given that my Chrome installation shows the same and I can surf. BTW: I am pretty sure you flushed the DNS server **cache** and not the server itself.

Comment: Yes IE works fine. I tested the windows firewall (turning it off, adding Chrome to allow list) and the antivirus I use and it did nothing. As far as the DNS flush I did in CMDPRMT: ipconfig /dnsflush And it said it successfully flushed it. I do have Covenant Eyes running on the computer btw.

Answer (score -1):

1. Please perform a reset on Google Chrome and make sure there is not any third party extension to block your connection.
2. Update your Windows and Firewall (Antivirus).
3. Check the date and time in your computer and make sure it's updated.
4. Remove the temp files from your computer and restart your computer.

See if that helps.